# Execute code only once

Tags: stepper

I am trying to create an if statement that only runs once, the very first time the void loop is started and switches to another code after that. But the following only executes stepper1a(). Any help would be great. Thx !

```c++
int var;
int var2;
bool executed = false;

const int M1dirpin = 4; //Stepper Dir Pin
const int M1steppin = 5; //Stepper Step Pin

void setup() {

pinMode(A2,INPUT);
pinMode(M1dirpin,OUTPUT);
pinMode(M1steppin,OUTPUT);
Serial.begin(9600);

}

void stepper1() { 
  int j;
    delayMicroseconds(10);
    digitalWrite(M1dirpin,HIGH);
  for(j=0;j<=200;j++){
    digitalWrite(M1steppin,LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(10);
    digitalWrite(M1steppin,HIGH);
    delay(2);
  }
}

void stepper1a() {
  int j;
    delayMicroseconds(10);
    digitalWrite(M1dirpin,HIGH);
  for(j=0;j<=1600;j++){
    digitalWrite(M1steppin,LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(10);
    digitalWrite(M1steppin,HIGH);
    delay(2);
  }
}

void loop() {

if (executed == false) {
var = analogRead(A2);
delay(10);
if (var > 500) {
  stepper1a();
  delay(2000);
  executed = true;
  Serial.println("turned 1600");
  Serial.println(executed);
  }
else if (executed == true) {
 var2 = analogRead(A2);
delay(10);
if (var > 500) {
  stepper1();
  delay(2000);
  Serial.println("turned 200");
}
}
}
}
```

Updated void loop:

```c++
void loop() {

    static bool yes_we_did_the_one_time_job = false;

    if (yes_we_did_the_one_time_job) {
        var = analogRead(A2);
        delay(10);
        if (var > 500) {
            stepper2();
            delay(2000);
            Serial.println("turned 1600");
        } 
    }
    else {
        var2 = analogRead(A2);
        delay(10);
        if (var > 500) {
            stepper1();
            delay(2000);
            Serial.println("turned 200");
            yes_we_did_the_one_time_job = true;
        }
    }
}
```

This works now, thx !!!:

```c++
void loop() {
  static bool yeswedid = false;

  if(yeswedid) {
    if(analogRead(A2) > 500) {
    stepper1();
    stepper2();
    }
  }
  else {
    if(analogRead(A2) > 500) {
    stepper1();
    yeswedid = true;
  }

  }
}
```

Comment: you have a typo. `else if (executed == true) {` is else to `if (var > 500) {`, not to `if (executed == false) {`. add one } before `else if (executed == true) {` and remove one } at the end

Comment: and `if (executed) {} else {}` would be cleaner

Comment: Your updated code is still wrong. You have have the code that sets yes_we_did_the_one_time_job to true inside a second if statement, which means it won't get set until after `var > 500`.

Comment: @DuncanC, that is the goal as I understand it. Wait until the analogRead first time reaches 500 and then do the special initialization move. because without the condition it could be executed in setup()

Comment: @digit - Question regarding your "Updated void loop:" code. The code `if (var > 500) {` in the `else` statement, is it suppose to be `var` or `var2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generic solution:

```cpp
void loop() {
    static bool yes_we_did_the_one_time_job = false;
    if (yes_we_did_the_one_time_job) {
        do_the_other_jobs();
    } else {
        do_the_one_time_job();
        yes_we_did_the_one_time_job = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: if this is what you suggest, it did not work:

Comment: see updated question. Thanks for your help

Comment: @digit: Re “_it did not work_”: you did not quite implement my suggestion. Read your code carefully and you will see it is not equivalent to what I posted here.

Comment: great solution thanks man !

Answer (score 2):

If you have any code you want to run only once at the beggining of your program you can use the `setup()` method. It can actually do much more than just setting up pins and default values.

The code of main function of Arduino ([main.cpp](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/cores/arduino/main.cpp)) looks like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    //(...) I cut some stuff from here

    setup();

    for (;;) {
        loop();
        if (serialEventRun) serialEventRun();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see `setup()` is just a method and it can do almost exactly the same things as `loop()`.

The `setup()` method can actually contain a `for(;;)` loop that will stop the program from running the `loop()` method. From inside it you can check the sensor value and `break` from it when condition is met.

```
void setup()
{
  for (;;)
  {
    var = analogRead(A2);
    delay(10);
    if (var > 500) {
      stepper1();
      delay(2000);
      Serial.println("turned 200");
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

in this case the `loop()` is very simple:

```
void loop()
{
  var = analogRead(A2);
  delay(10);
  if (var > 500)
  {
    stepper2();
    delay(2000);
    Serial.println("turned 1600");
  }
}
```

Comment: It has to react to a sensor while in void loop and not run once at startup. Thanks.

Comment: only once, but after a starting condition is met. the OP's code is usable, only a { is missing